# Geoip shortcodes in comments

Tags: shortcode, comments

I am wondering how can I add a country shortcode from geoip plugin (https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/) into comment field.

[geoip_detect2 property="country"]

From what I noticed comment field has to be a wysiwyg field (not text as it is by default). Is there any other way to do this? By custom php function or so?

Regards,
Michal

Comment: Are you expecting commenters to use that shortcode in their comments? Or are you really asking how to show a commeter's country when they comment?

Comment: You'll want to be very careful with page caching, it looks like your question is "How do I enable shortcodes in comments". What problem does the geoip shortcode being usable in comments solve?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution by myself just by using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-shortcodes-inside-widgetscomments-and-experts/